# Non-geographical maps in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

[Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) provides the possibility of [creating non-geographical maps](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html) by using `CRS.Simple` where

> [...] one horizontal map unit is mapped to one horizontal pixel, and *idem* with vertical.

For the sake of simplicity it can be said that this allows creating maps using pixels as units of measurement. However, I do not use Leaflet, I use [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/) (which works pretty well).

Is there any way to implement non-geographical maps in OpenLayers? Looking at its API or examples I couldn't find anything useful so far.

Comment: You can define a pixels projection as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/static-image.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Mike! The example [Static Image](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/static-image.html) was the right advice to look at.

The following code creates a 4000 x 2000 pixel large map with a feature representing its bounding box:

```
const extent = [0, 0, 4000, 2000];

const projection = new Projection({
  code: 'pixel-map',
  units: 'pixels',
  extent
});

const geojsonObject = {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: [
    {
      type: 'Feature',
      geometry: {
        type: 'LineString',
        coordinates: [[0, 0], [0, extent[3]], [extent[2], extent[3]], [extent[2], 0], [0, 0]]
      }
    }
    // More Features
    // ...
  ]
};

const vectorSource = new VectorSource({
  features: (new GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geojsonObject),
  format: new GeoJSON()
});

const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource
});

const map = new Map({
  target: 'my-pixel-map',
  layers: [
    vectorLayer
  ],
  view: new View({
    projection,
    center: getCenter(extent),
    zoom: 2,
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 8
  })
});
```